# How does one use a outfile in MYSQL while also allowing the program to run twice without an error?

Tags: mysql

I created a program for my assignment but I can't seem to get it the way the professor prefers.

I used DROP TABLE IF EXIST but when it comes to the outfile when running twice it tells me that the file already exists. How can I get it to ignore it after it exists?

```
SELECT * FROM Web JOIN Web2 ON Web.ID = Web2.ID

INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramFiles/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/assignment.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL refuses to overwrite an existing file. This is on purpose. It's a security feature, to prevent someone using SQL to hack into your database server, for example by overwriting `/etc/passwd`.

This is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

You have to use `SELECT...INTO OUTFILE` to write to a non-existing filename. If you need to do it again, either manually remove the file first, or else write to a unique filename.